# Changing contents of <span> is affecting placement of other elements in line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a group of `<spans>` as below (ignore the inline styles):

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
            <span id="ears" class="disable-selection" style="display: inline-block;" onclick="increase('earNumber', ears)" oncontextmenu="decrease('earNumber', ears) ">( )</span>
            <span id="mouths" class="disable-selection" style="display: inline-block;" onclick="increase( 'mouthNumber', mouths)" oncontextmenu="decrease('mouthNumber', mouths)">( )</span>
            <span id="eyes" class="disable-selection" style="display: inline-block;" onclick="increase( 'eyeNumber', eyes)" oncontextmenu="decrease('eyeNumber', eyes)">( )</sp>
 </div>
```

And when I am using javascript to change the content of each ear but when I do the other elements move up and down as below:

> The text on the right is above all the others

[image: Before]

> The elements are now all inline after changing the text on the right

[image: After]

Below is my CSS:

```
div span, button
    cursor: pointer

span
    text-align: center
    font-size: 20px
    width: 120px
    height: 30px
    border: 1px solid black
    display: block
```

I want to have all the elements remain inline but I am unsure how.

> ## Edit: Complete Code Below

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <button onclick="copy()" id="container" title="Copy">&#128203</button>
    <button onclick="paste()" title="Paste"></button>
    <button onclick="clearInput()" title="Clear">️</button>
    <button onclick="edit()" title="Edit">✏️</button>
    <button onclick="shuffle()" title="Random"></button>
</div>
```

```css
div span, button {
    cursor: pointer;
}
span {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
}
```

```js
var ears = ['⸮ ?','ᕮ ᕭ', '| |']
var eyes = ['ᴗ ᴗ', '► ◄', '✪ ✪']
var mouths = ['ᨓ', 'ө', '﹏']
//Change Face in Input
function setFace() {
    faceEars = ears[earNumber].split(" ");
    faceEyes = eyes[eyeNumber].split(" ");
    document.getElementById('faceOutput').value = faceEars[0] + faceEyes[0] + mouths[mouthNumber] + faceEyes[1] + faceEars[1];
    document.getElementById('ears').innerHTML = ears[earNumber];
    document.getElementById('eyes').innerHTML = eyes[eyeNumber];
    document.getElementById('mouths').innerHTML = mouths[mouthNumber];
}
//Increase Part Value
function increase(number, arr) {
    window[number] >= arr.length - 1 ? window[number] = 0 : window[number] += 1;
    setFace();
}
//Decrease Part Value
function decrease(number, arr) {
    window[number] <= 0 ? window[number] = arr.length - 1 : window[number] -= 1;
    setFace();
}
```

Comment: Please share a snippet of working code so we can play around :)

Comment: your styling seems inconsistent. with external css, span said `display: block`, but with inline css it said `display: inline-block`. why ?  you should also share more code.

Comment: Ok so this is actually for an electron app that takes an array from a .txt doc but the code in my edit should work

Comment: @CanUver I didn't even realise, I'm not excellent at CSS

Comment: vertical-align:top to your elements